# User Control is not posting its form values

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a user control I am adding dynamically.
It has a link button and a text area on it. The containing div is hidden via style sheet (client side), and I use some jquery to pop it up in a modal.
It is getting added in the init and the button click event is firing on the server.
BUT the textareas value is not being set. On further inspection the field value is not even being sent in the form POST data.

Any ideas why the value is not being sent. The rest of the form values are being sent with no problems.

Comment: Probably when you open it in an inside windows you clone or move the input or something like that and the form is losing it. Need some more code for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the control is actually being added to a form control. Your link button will still post back even if it's outside the form as it's a javascript call, but there won't be any content from your server controls in postdata.

Comment: yep I had this - by default jquery dialog gets tacked on the DOM afteer the form:first. You need to add some code to append the .dialog to the asp.net form. This can have the detrimental effect of modifying the control heirachy so sometimes the viewstate gets mangled (any ideas why) but anyway (.js -> pop.parent().appendTo($('form:first')); where 'pop' is the jquery popup that has been created